# Adding a slide down search box to navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, search

I am trying to build a slide down search box.  I want the search box to slide down once your press the search icon.  (I want it exactly like this - http://www.marieclaire.co.uk/).  When it slides down I want it to be full width.  I have started to build the actual search box, but I can't figure out how to get it to slide down from a search icon. Does anyone have any solutions?

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zx06d7vz/ (search box at bottom of screen)

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Search
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.search-site {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 15px
}

.search-form {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    background: #fff;
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: calc((100vw - 1200px) / 2);
    padding-right: calc((100vw - 1200px) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% + 1px);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 999999
}

.search-form.search-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 200px
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent {
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 100px !important;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    transform: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent .input-group {
    padding: 0;
    top: 0
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent .button-search {
    color: #33f;
    outline: none
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent .button-search:hover {
    color: #b4c5cd
}

.search-form .input-group {
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 72px;
    width: 100%
}

.search-form .form-control {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px #b4c5cd solid;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    width: calc(100% - 36px) !important
}

.search-form .form-control:focus {
    background: #fff !important
}

.search-form .button-search {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 6px 0 0 0;
    width: 36px
     background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-search-strong-128.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form form-inline search-visible" action="">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="search" value="" name="s" class="input-sm search-field form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <button type="submit" class="button-search icon-search"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: This snippet has way too much code for JSFiddle, it is very difficult to work with in a horribad split screen viewer. I recommend breaking your problem down, and removing alot of these useless navigation menus right now. Focus on building the search feature, then add your menus back in correctly. Otherwise, I can't help.

Comment: I edited it down

Answer (score 1):

Test that one.

HTML:

```
<h1 class="search">S</h1>
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form form-inline" action="">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="search" value="" name="s" class="input-sm search-field form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <button type="submit" class="button-search icon-search"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**CSS**

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Search
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.search-site {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 15px
}

.search-form {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out 250ms ease;
    background: #fff;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: calc((100vw - 1200px) / 2);
    padding-right: calc((100vw - 1200px) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 999999
}

.search-form.search-visible {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent {
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 100px !important;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    transform: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent .input-group {
    padding: 0;
    top: 0
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent .button-search {
    color: #33f;
    outline: none
}

.search-form.search-form-permanent .button-search:hover {
    color: #b4c5cd
}

.search-form .input-group {
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 72px;
    width: 100%
}

.search-form .form-control {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px #b4c5cd solid;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    width: calc(100% - 36px) !important
}

.search-form .form-control:focus {
    background: #fff !important
}

.search-form .button-search {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 6px 0 0 0;
    width: 36px
     background: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-search-strong-128.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.search').on('click', function () {
 $('.search-form').addClass('search-visible');
});
```

Comment: This is only example of your thing. So check diferences between your and my code. In my example you have to click on "S" to slide down searching bar. Akcept answer if it worked ;)

Comment: you can change this addClass to toggleClass. Then you can hide and show this bar on click.

Comment: Thank you it works.  Is there a way that I can also hide the search bar if you click anywhere else off the search bar?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do. I will change soon this jQuery code.

Comment: Did you ever edit the jQuery code? I still can't hide the search bar by clicking anywhere else but the search bar.